# How do I get data from 2 SQL tables and put it in a single HTML table?

Tags: php, html, mysql

PHP is here:

```
 <?php
    $sth = $conn->prepare('SELECT employee.name, employee.type, employee.rate, work.overtime, work.leaves, work.ticket FROM employee, work');
   $sth->execute();
     $data = $sth->fetchAll();   
    foreach ($data as $row ){
        if($row['name']!=""){
    ?>
```

HTML:

```
<tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" value="<?php echo $row['name']?>"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Type" value="<?php echo $row['type']?>"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Rate" value="<?php echo $row['rate']?>"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="OT" value="<?php echo $row['overtime']?>"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Leaves" value="<?php echo $row['leaves']?>"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Total" value="<?php echo $row['ticket']?>"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Snapshots of tables:
[image]

And the other:
[image]

Name is common between the two.

How do I display the data?

Comment: do a join query. join between two table with name field

Comment: joining two table `employee, work` on the basic of any command thing like any common id ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you are looking for is `JOIN`. Read the manual of [MySQL Official Doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $sth = $conn->prepare('SELECT employee.name, employee.type, employee.rate, work.overtime, work.leaves, work.ticket FROM employee left join work on employee.name=work.name');
   $sth->execute();
     $data = $sth->fetchAll();   
    foreach ($data as $row ){
        if($row['name']!=""){
    ?>
```

Then Your HTML Code will be like this (Make sure you are using `<tr>` under `<table>` tag.)

```
<tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" value="<?php echo $row['name']?>"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Type" value="<?php echo $row['type']?>"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Rate" value="<?php echo $row['rate']?>"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="OT" value="<?php echo $row['overtime']?>"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Leaves" value="<?php echo $row['leaves']?>"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Total" value="<?php echo $row['ticket']?>"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Here I am using left join because you may require your all employee name. if you want only common records between these two tables then simply use inner join instead of left join.